# An error occurred during the signature verification

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, wsl-2

error when trying to apt update and apt upgrade

'E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian jammy Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8